# What are the idmso's for the context menu for text in a Task Item and Appointment Item

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

In a VSTO outlook 2010 project I have successfully used the "ContextMenuReadOnlyMailText" to add a context menu to a mail item when the user right clicks on text within the mail item.  What is the idmso for the same thing within a Task Item and within an Appointment item?

I found "ContextMenuReadOnlyMailText" in the WordControls.xlsx from the Office2010ControlIDs.

As I cannot find anything in there for Task or Appointment items then maybe they do not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out.  In the WordControls there is a "ContextMenuText" and if you use this as the idmso for a task item or appointment item it works.

I could be wrong here but it appears that "ContextMenuText" works as the idmso for most text context menus in the body of an Outlook item except for a read mail item.